# Handle notifications with Cordova in background

Tags: android, cordova, background, notifications, push

I'm using org.jboss.aerogear.cordova.push 1.1.0 for push notifications on my Cordova app.

When I receive a notification with the app in the foreground, the onNotification event gets triggered and manages the notification data within the app just fine. However, if a notification is received when the app is in the background, a drawer notification is shown and the app receives the notification data only if I open the app by clicking on the notification itself.

How can I fix this so that the app always receives the notification data even without clicking on the drawer notification? (possibly as soon as the notification is received rather than when the app is opened, but that's not mandatory).

Comment: I'm working with cordova as well and am running into the same issue. Were you able to find a solution (to get onNotification triggered while the app is in the background)?